# What could be causing this overprint?

Tags: overprint

I have just received prints from a company and saw that an image was missing from one of the pages. I asked the company about this and they investigated to find out that the file contains and overprint which caused the image not to print. (I've sent things to print thousands of times, over a decade and this is the first time this has happened to me.)

I have checked the InDesign file and the overprint preview doesn't show anything, but it does show up in Acrobat on the resulting PDF export.

[image: Overprint Preview turned on in Indesign]

[image: The result in PDF when simulate overprint is applied]

I don't understand what's happened here or where that overprint came from, other pages have overprint and the issue does not appear there.

I re-exported the file to PDF in the exact same way and this didn't have that overprint.

What could be causing that problem? Is there anything I need to not to pre-empt this issue?

Comment: One would have to examine your document to be able to determine what the problem is. That's why I voted to close. There are some bugs in InDesign. For example both setting an object to "overprint fill" and setting its blend mode to *multiply* can give unexpected results. And using blend modes on content frames (as opposed to container frames) also gives trouble sometimes. Try to examine that object closely. Does it have fill color, effects, blend modes?

Comment: One weird thing is that overprint puts "more ink", not making an object to be hidden under another...

Comment: @Wolff there are no effects in the document at all, we don't use anything like as part of the brand toolkit. There are 5-6 other pages with the overprint, but none of them has this problem. Its this single image. I did nothing different than any other time. Placed a rectangle frame, gave it rounded corners and dropped in an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the art file. Illustrator has overprint options: Window > Attributes. A mistake I’ve made before is to change a logo from black to white, forget to uncheck overprint, and the logo disappears on the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago i had that problem in indesign because of a missing link. I did the export to pdf and the result was exactly that one... white container with no image.
Did you check your links?

Answer (score 0):

If it was an overprint issue my best guess is that your image somewhat exported incorrectly and interpreted as a white CMYK (0/0/0/0) image or object as Nuno wrote, overprinting a device 0/0/0/0 will cause a knockout on underlying CMYK. (see image, middle top patch)

@Rafael
I wish it would be that simple...
Depending on color space and colorants, you can get a bit confused with overprinting.
See image. 40/40/20/40 (CMYK) stipes, OPM1.
Left top: overprint without colorant (classic "white overprint")
Left bottom: overprint separation space cyan 0%
Middle top: overprint raster image with 0/0/0/0
Middle bottom: overprint device CMYK 100/0/0/0
Right top: overprint raster image deviceN M/Y 40/4
Right bottom: overprint raster image deviceN M/Y 56/56

[image]